# Piping bluetooth signal throught internet

Tags: bluetooth

I'm wondering if there is a way to pipe the signal of a Bluetooth device through internet and repeat it from another location. In detail, I have a device "transmitter1" that can establish a connection with another device, "reciver2". I want to pipe the signal through internet to be able to have transmitter1 in one location and reciver2 in another one. I'm wondering if there is a way to encode this signal, send it through https and decode it an transmit it again in the second location.

Something like: Transmitter1-> Reciever1 -> Https -> Transmiter2-> Reciver2.

So, I guess my question is: Can one pipe a Bluetooth connection through internet?

Comment: What would prevent it? You just need to encode the received BT packet for sending over the internet and decode and retransmit it on the other side. A live example - bluetooth headsets which are used on two sides of Skype conversation (well, it is not exactly the same bluetooth signal, but consider the voice kind of "lossy encoding").

Comment: Which kind of approach would you suggest to 1. enode the signal and 2 retransmit on the other side? I know how to handle the https pipe, but no the how to encode/decode it.

Comment: I bet there is nothing preventing that, so it must be possible given enough hardware and software developement. It may depend on which exact devices you would be replicating.

Comment: Bluetooth data is just it - binary data. Just pack it and wrap with any metadata you might find useful.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to everyone for the comments

Comment: @EugeneSh. "What would prevent it?" The need for bidirectional data exchange with hard time limits.

Comment: @Marcus This would depend on what exactly is required to be transmitted. If it is the data payload only, then the handshake can be handled by the local receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Something like: Transmitter1-> Reciever1 -> Https -> Transmiter2-> Reciver2.

That won't work: BT is a bidirectional protocol¹, so, there's no one-sided "I broadcast this data"; there's handshakes and aknowledgements that need to go from Receiver2 to Transmitter1 in your chain.

The problem with that is that there's a finite temporal window for these – and you can't achieve that with transfer through an encrypted internet transport.

---

¹ "proper" BT is, BTLE / beacons are not

Comment: Well, In that case, may be I can use a TCP connection via socket, right? I can edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: no. Latency is going to be too high. Generally, TCP would also not be the transport of choice for such applications – packets that need to get re-sent or re-ordered are simply going to be useless, anyway.

Comment: Ok... So, there's not really a way to do that, right?

Comment: so, first of all, you still haven't solved the bidirectionality problem. it really doesn't work in just one way. Then, the bluetooth physical layer gives a slave station some 150 µs to reply. Can your computer, your network, your operating system and your radio hardware on both sides do things in less than 150 µs?

Comment: No, no, It cannot. I would have to think about an alternative approach. Like reciver1, establish the connection and just ask for indications for transmiter2, but the connection must be established between transmitter1 and reciver1.

Comment: @Marcus I don't think the ask here is to emulate the lowest BT layer over the internet. It's up to OP to clarify it.But to me it sounds like transmitting the data payload (like voice, or serial data or whatever this BT us used for).